# Grails - testing custom validator on domain class issue

Tags: grails, grails-validation

I'm learning grails from Grails - getting started by Jason Rudolph book.
My domain class looks like that:

```
class Race {

  String name;
  Date startDateTime
  String city
  String state
  Float distance
  Float cost
  Integer maxRunners = 10000

  static hasMany = [registrations: Registration]

  static constraints = {
    name(maxSize: 50, blank: false)
    startDateTime(validator: {
      return it > new Date()
    })
    city(maxSize: 30, blank: false)
    state(inList: ['GA', 'NC', 'SC', 'VA'], blank: false)
    distance(min: 3.1f, max: 100f)
    cost(min: 0f, max: 999.99f)
  }

  String toString() { "${this.name} : ${this.city}, ${this.state}" }
}
```

I want to test the custom validation of startDateTime field. Test looks like that:

```
class RaceTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
  protected void setUp() {
    super.setUp()
  }

  protected void tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
  }

  void testCustomDateValidation() {
    def race = new Race()
    race.startDateTime = null
    assertFalse(race.validate())
  }
}
```

Test looks similar to the one from book I mentioned earlier. But I'm getting

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: racetrack.Race.validate() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

I'm stuck and didn't find any solution :/ Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You mention you're using Jason Rudolph's book so I assume you're using the 1st edition. This is _very_ dated and you should be using the 2nd edition which is also free: http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/grails-getting-started

Comment: Yup, as it turned out I was using the older edition - I knew there was second edition, but I forgot to download it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use unit tests or mocking to test domain classes. Grails does create a unit test for domain classes and this should be changed. Move the class to the same package and folder under test/integration and change the base class to GroovyTestCase and you'll have a proper test that runs with the in-memory database and tests persistence, not the mocking framework.

Comment: I assume the rationale is that mocking does not provide the same behaviour than the real DB. The downside is unit tests run much more faster than integration test. For TDD integration tests are IMHO too slow. So I'll stick with unit testing here.

Comment: @Burt Beckwith, can you provide some reasoning behind your statement that unit test/mocking should not be used to test domain classes?  That is a disturbing statement since I have so many tests doing just that. More disturbing (as you pointed out) is that Grails automatically creates a unit test for domain classes.  Additionally Grails in Action chapter 7.2.1 specifically says to use unit test to test domain class constraints. If we really should not be using unit tests for testing domain classes I hope these things get fixed sooner than later to prevent unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Testing constraints using unit tests is ok, although testing a unique constraint in-memory with only mocking is not realistic since it's backed in reality by a database feature. Keep in mind that the in-memory "database" in unit tests isn't H2, and certainly isn't the database you're using in dev or prod, it's a `ConcurrentHashMap`. The risk is pretty high that you'll get false positives when testing persistence using mocking.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the mockForConstraintsTests() call. The common pattern is to do this in setUp()

```
protected void setUp() {
  super.setUp()
  mockForConstraintsTests(Race)    
}
```

For details: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/04/unit-testing-constraints-in-domain.html